# get checked values for jsTree - submit with form post

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

I'm using the jsTree jQuery plugin with the checkbox theme.  Does anyone know how to get the selected values with a form post?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you got your answer ? If not, here is one that appears in the [jstree google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/topics)

```
    function submitMe(){ 
        var checked_ids = []; 
        $("#server_tree").jstree("get_checked",null,true).each 
            (function () { 
                checked_ids.push(this.id); 
            }); 
           doStuff(checked_ids);
```

Answer (score 31):

In the last version (3.0), the API was changed.

If you need just array of selected IDs (like in examples in this node), it is now very easy:

```
var selectedElmsIds = $('#tree').jstree("get_selected");
```

If you need to iterate over the selected elements, you just need to pass additional "true" parameter.

```
var selectedElmsIds = [];
var selectedElms = $('#tree').jstree("get_selected", true);
$.each(selectedElms, function() {
    selectedElmsIds.push(this.id);
});
```

Comment: For me, on 3.3.4 I needed to use get_checked, not get_selected.

Comment: Using 3.3.8 version of jsTree, it is get_selected. For complete and working source code, you can have a look at https://everyething.com/Example-of-jsTree-to-get-all-checked-nodes

Answer (score 15):

Everyone, who worked with Jstree’s may face to this question: How to get the checked Ids of Jstree in form submit? here is the solution:

```
function submitMe() {
    var checked_ids = [];
    $('#your-tree-id').jstree("get_checked",null,true).each(function(){
        checked_ids.push(this.id);
    });
    //setting to hidden field
    document.getElementById('jsfields').value = checked_ids.join(",");
}
```

Now, we set it in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="jsfields" id="jsfields" value="" />
```

Comment: hi, so this.id refers to what exactely ? and what if I want to get the text of the a tag ? Thanks.

Comment: I get it :) It refers to the id of the tag li.

Comment: Does this also get items in an "undetermined" state?

Answer (score 3):

The suggested solution from google groups however didn't work for partially checked nodes, in my case. I had to leave the get_checked out and do the following to get fully selected and partially selected nodes.

`$(".sector-tree").find(".jstree-undetermined").each(function(i,element){            
    checked_ids.push($(element).attr("id"));

    if ($(this).find(".jstree-undetermined").length == 0) {  
        $(this).find(".jstree-checked").each(function(i, element){          
            checked_ids.push({$(element).attr("id"));
        });         
    }
});

// collect the rest of the checked nodes that exist under checked parents
$(".sector-tree").find(".jstree-checked").each(function(i, element){ //also includes the ones below 'undetermined' parent

    var selectedElement = $(element).attr("id");
    if ( hasItem(selectedElement, checked_ids ) < 0 ) {             
        checked_ids.push(selectedElement);
    }

});`

Answer (score 3):

With `jQuery` you can simply do:

```
$('.jstree-checked,.jstree-undetermined').each(function(){
    var rawCheckedID = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
});
```

This will get the undetermined and checked at the same time. soumya's solution above may be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
var result = $('#your_tree').jstree('get_selected');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22499278/1883345

Answer (score 1):

i did this to get id,parentid and text of selected checkbox. hopefully it will help someone :)

```
function myFunction(elmnt,clr){
         elmnt.style.color =clr;
         var selectedElmsinfo = [];

         var selectedElms = $('#SimpleJSTree').jstree("get_selected", true);
            $.each(selectedElms, function() {
                selectedElmsinfo.push(this.id,this.text,this.parent);

            });
             alert(selectedElmsinfo);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//click button show nodes checked
$(document).on('click','#showme',function() {
    var checked_ids = [];
    var checked_ids_meta = [];
    $('#demo_0').jstree("get_checked",null,true).each(function(i, e){
        checked_ids.push($(this).data("param")); // json metadata
        checked_ids_meta.push($(this).attr("href")); // json attr
    });     
    console.log(checked_ids)
    console.log(checked_ids_meta)       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selectedElmsIds = [];
$("#jstree2").find("li").each(function(i, element) { //also includes the ones below 'undetermined' parent
  if ($(this).attr("aria-selected") == "true") {
    selectedElmsIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
  }
});
console.log(selectedElmsIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

This I did:

```
function getSelectedItems()
{
    var checked_ids = [];

    checkedNodes = $("#MyTree").jstree("get_checked", null, true); 

    for(var i = 0; i < checkedNodes.length; i++)
    {
        var id = $(checkedNodes[i].outerHTML)[0].id;

        checked_ids.push(id);
    }

     // Do whatever you want with the checked_ids 
}
```

This will give you an array of all selected node and their sub nodes and leafs; as well as single leafs selected under other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var jsfields = $('#myTree').jstree('get_selected');
$('.jsfields').val(JSON.stringify([jsfields]));
})

<input type="hidden" class="jsfields" value=""/>
```

Change the value of `$('#myTree')` to you respective tree, this is best working for me in ajax call. slight modification may be needed to populate input field of simple form.