# How to get all checked nodes in jstree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I need to export my nodes like this:

```
function recursive_simplify(node){ 
    if(node.children){
        for(var i =0;i<node.children.length;i++){
            node.children[i] = recursive_simplify(node.children[i])
        }
    }
    delete node['metadata'];
    return node
}

$('body').on('click','.data-export', function () {
    var tree=$.jstree._reference('#reference-data-exchange');
    var checked = tree.get_checked(); 
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0, checkedLength = checked.length; i<checkedLength;i++)
    {
      var checkedJson = tree.get_json(checked[i],['id','rel','data-bin','data-pos'])[0];
      checkedJson = recursive_simplify(checkedJson);
      result.push(checkedJson);
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

it's works fine, BUT! I need all checked nodes(checked & undetermined)
My code returns only checked.
Plz help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048001/get-checked-values-for-jstree-submit-with-form-post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
get_all_checked: function(obj)
           {
                obj = !obj || obj === -1 ? this.get_container() : this._get_node(obj);
                return obj.find(".jstree-checked, .jstree-undetermined");
            };
```

use :

```
var checkedNodes = $(this).jstree("get_all_checked");
```

Comment: $(this).jstree("get_all_checked");  only returns the node that was clicked, not the entire tree.

Answer (score 0):

Using 3.3.8 version of jsTree, to get all the undetermined nodes, `get_undetermined` option is available.

Hence, you can use both `get_selected` and `get_undetermined` to fulfil your requirement.

For complete and working source code, you can refer https://everyething.com/Example-of-jsTree-to-get-all-checked-nodes