# get the parent and child id of js tree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using jsTree 3.3.1 and the following image is the tree generated. Now you can see i have selected D and E, then its parents(B and C ) also selected. I would like to get the selected parents(B and C) id along with the childs(D and E).  I have used the following function and it not working for me. Also i have found [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049874/how-to-get-all-checked-nodes-in-jstree) which is not working for me. Any help really appreciated.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVzum.jpg)

```
var arr = new Array();
$("#testtree").jstree('get_checked').each(function(index) {
arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result returned by `get_checked` is a plain array of ids, while you are trying to iterate it as a jQuery collection. Also you will need to grab id's of parents with undetermined status. So you could use code as below. Also check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/r2swfqfn/)

```
  var arr = $("#testtree").jstree('get_checked');

  $("#testtree").find(".jstree-undetermined").each(
    function(i, element) {
        arr.push( $(element).closest('.jstree-node').attr("id") );
    }
);
```