# Get Checked Element in JQuery JStree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have created one Jquery jstree with JSON object. My tree is working fine

**Creating jstree**

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "data": [{
            "data": "pe_opensourcescanning",
            "id": 0,
            "pId": -1,
            "children": [{
                "data": "tags",
                "id": 30,
                "pid": 0
            }, {
                "data": "branches",
                "id": 29,
                "pid": 0
            }, {
                "data": "trunk",
                "id": 1,
                "pid": 0,
                "children": [{
                    "data": "import-export",
                    "id": 28,
                    "pid": 1
                }, {
                    "data": "custom_development",
                    "id": 12,
                    "pid": 1
                }, {
                    "data": "Connectors",
                    "id": 7,
                    "pid": 1
                }, {
                    "data": "support",
                    "id": 6,
                    "pid": 1
                }, {
                    "data": "Installation-Configuration",
                    "id": 5,
                    "pid": 1
                }, {
                    "data": "backup",
                    "id": 2,
                    "pid": 1
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "ui"]
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id"));
});
```

Now i want the "id" and "data" values for each checked nodes. I have tried to write something but unfortunately that doesn't work. Kindly help me how to achieve this goal.

**Getting checked nodes**

```
$("#tree").jstree("get_checked",null,true).each(function () { 
    alert(this.data);
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048001/get-checked-values-for-jstree-submit-with-form-post

Comment: I had already seen that. but in my case "this.id" and "this.data" are coming as void.

Comment: try console.log(this);  that should help point you in the right direction

Comment: @Rooster i have tried as u suggested. it gives me in the console as "<li class="jstree-leaf jstree-checked">". what is the meaning of  it. where is the problem in my code. please help me.

Comment: jstree mimics checkboxes unless you set the param to tell it to use real ones.  Maybe you have.  You can try a console.log($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]'));  if its length is one just grab the id and data from that, if it 0 then you need to grab the id and data from whereever its being stored in relation to the li element.

Comment: @Rooster i am getting the output as zero. now what i have to do. please tell me in brief as i am very new in jquery and json.

Comment: inspect the DOM and figure out what element has the data and id  youre trying to reach and target that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function to get checked nodes is right, the problem is your JSON that is not well-formed; to set property on the tree, so they can't be get from the methods.

You must use the property `attr` or no data will be set on the node, from the docs:

> The attr object will appear as attributes on the resulting li node.

Code:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "data": [{
            "data": "pe_opensourcescanning",
                "attr": {
                "id": 77,
                    "pId": -1
            },
                "children": [{
                "data": "tags",
                    "attr": {
                    "id": 30,
                        "pid": 0
                }
            }, {
                "data": {
                    "title": "branches"
                },
                    "attr": {
                    "id": 29,
                        "pid": 0
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "ui"]
})

$("#getChecked").click(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree("get_checked", null, true).each(function (i, e) {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"))
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RYhgD/

Docs: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion. The problrleme has been resolved now.